# how you will fit custom data into Quickblox on the backend - (using Quickblox user data storage of custom settings, game scores, etc)?

Tags: javascript

how you will fit custom data into Quickblox on the backend - (using Quickblox user data storage of custom settings, game scores, etc)?

Comment: Read the documentation Of Quickblox and show what you tried

Comment: can YOU explain something regarding this

Comment: yes but u should show your code on your question the I can help you